# What is this visual artifact in vim?

Tags: osx, vim, iterm2

I am using vim in iTerm2 on OSX Mojave.

When I hit the key combo: `⌘` + `;` at line 67, a blue bar appears beneath the line:

[image]

I don't know what is it for and not sure if it is a vim function.

Anyone know what is this blue bar is for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [an iTerm feature](https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-highlights.html), not a Vim one:

[image: Session -> Open Autocomplete]

> #### Autocomplete
>
> Any text that exists in a tab or its scrollback buffer can be
>   autocompleted in that tab. To use autocomplete, type the beginning of
>   a word and then press cmd-;. An autocomplete window opens showing the
>   top 20 choices for words beginning what you have entered. The list can
>   be filtered by typing a subsequence. The filter can be reset by
>   pressing backspace. If you make a selection and press return, it will
>   be entered for you. If you make a selection and press tab, your
>   autocomplete will be extended with the selection.